# How to toggle pushbutton when contiously receiving serial port data in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, serial-port, qtserialport

I have designed a GUI in pyqt5. All other functions are working well but if I press the pushbutton (Connect) I receiving the continuous data from serial port (it's working fine) but it is going in a infinite loop so lateron I am unable to toggle the push button i.e. stop the continous data.
Code : Part of the code(skipped some part that was working fine)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets,QtSerialPort
import traceback,serial

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 60, 101, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, -10, 221, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 81, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 141, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 201, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 240, 81, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 330, 251, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 651, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 150, 381, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.textBrowser.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.textBrowser_2 = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 371, 731, 181))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.textBrowser_2.setFont(font)
        self.textBrowser_2.setObjectName("textBrowser_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 330, 101, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 330, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 70, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_6.setFont(font)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 60, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.comboBox_2.setFont(font)
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_2.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Connect)
        self.pushButton.toggle()
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.Send)            

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)  
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Serial Port"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Connect"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Serial Data"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Port "))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Status :"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Request"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Message Log"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Clear"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "COM8"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "COM1"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "COM2"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "COM3"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(4, _translate("MainWindow", "COM4"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(5, _translate("MainWindow", "COM5"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(6, _translate("MainWindow", "COM6"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(7, _translate("MainWindow", "COM7"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(8, _translate("MainWindow", "COM9"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(9, _translate("MainWindow", "COM10"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(10, _translate("MainWindow", "COM11"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(11, _translate("MainWindow", "COM12"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(12, _translate("MainWindow", "COM13"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Baudrate"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "9600"))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "115200"))


    def Connect(self):
        port=self.comboBox.currentText()
        baudrate=self.comboBox_2.currentText()
            
        serialPort = serial.Serial(port =port, baudrate=baudrate,
                       bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

        serialString = " "

        while 1:
            if(serialPort.in_waiting > 0):
                serialString = serialPort.readline()

                print(serialString.decode('Ascii'))
                self.textBrowser.setText("Connected")
                self.textBrowser_2.append(serialString.decode('Ascii'))
                self.textBrowser_2.repaint()


                if  self.pushButton.isEnabled():
                    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1, self.Connect)
                else:
                            #self.file.close()
                    self.pushButton.toggle()
                    serialPort.close()
    
    def Send(self):
        port=self.comboBox.currentText()
        baudrate=self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        serialPort = serial.Serial(port =port, baudrate=baudrate,
                       bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

        serialString = ""

        serialPort.write(str.encode(self.lineEdit_2.text()))
        #print(serialString.decode('ascii'))
        self.textBrowser_2.append(self.lineEdit_2.text())
        self.textBrowser_2.repaint()
        self.lineEdit_2.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It is optimum to use a QThread here. You can toggle the working of your QThread on button click

Comment: It's not only optimum, but almost mandatory. **No** blocking operation (like a while loop or using `time.sleep`) should **ever** happen in the main Qt thread.